# Batch command to use the first line of txt file to create a file

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file which is reading another txt file and send the values to the external exe file, which generates an output file with the out of these commands.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (data.txt) do (
:start

XYZ.exe %%A )
```

and the content of data.txt is like this:

```
abc 1 2
xyz 2 3
```

Now, i am editing the data.txt like this:

```
name of file: mp3
abc 1 2
xyz 2 3
name of file: mp4
sss 1 2
rrr 2 3
name of file: vob
eee 1 2
qqq 2 3
```

and i need to use the name of File to create a file with the extension name as mentioned  every time to append in the last.

Edited:

I mainly need to find a way that i can save the value of name of file in a variable every time it comes. So, for example in the above text file, when i run the batch, it will see if name of the file exists or not. If it exists then it will save the value i.e. mp3 in above case and save it and then call the XYZ.exe until the name of file dont come again. As soon the new file name comes, a method will call which will merge the two outputs generated by the XYZ form the two parameters and merge them into a file and append the extension of that file with a mp3.

Then again the new file name will get saved in the same variable and the process continues.

If there is not a single instance of this file name in the data.txt, the extension will be txt for the resultant file. I think it should be clear now. Please let me know for more clarifications..

Comment: Since we don't know how your `xyz` program would accept an output file name we can't really help you here. And I had to read that question four times or so to get an idea of what you're trying.

Comment: XYZ program just take three parameters and returns a file. And that is not really the issue. and i just need to append the extension name with that file generated. The issue is how can we detect that there is a new file name in the data.txt file and we need to stop processing further commands and just append this extension to the file generated.

Comment: ok, i have edited my query for clear query with example. Hope it helps..!

Answer (score 1):

I would specify the names *not before* the corresponding lines with parameters, but *after* them. If the name goes first, the processing is going to be more complex: you need to check if it's the first line or not, because if it is not, you first need to use a previously stored name to merge the pending output files and only *then* store the new name. Also, when you reach the end of `data.txt`, there'll be no `name of file` line to trigger the merger of the last set of output items. In contrast, if the name goes after the params, you just use it there and then, you don't even need to store it.

Probably you could do it like this:

1. Store `%%A` in a variable.
2. Try removing `name of file:`  from the stored value (using the `set var=!var:substr=!` syntax).
3. Compare the resulting value with `%%A`.
4. If the two values remain identical, then there was no `name of file:`  substring in `%%A`, which means it's a parameter list line, not a file name line. (I do hope you are not going to ever use that signature string as a parameter set.) In this case,

   - just call the .exe file to process the params, like you are doing presently.
5. If the values turned out different, then the line contain a name. Therefore,

   - if it's not the first name, process the output files using a previously stored name;
   - store the name just obtained for later use;
   - set a flag indicating that the following name will not be the first one.
6. After the loop, process the old name if the flag is set.

Below is my attempt at implementing the above list of steps:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelatedExpansion
SET NotTheFirstName=

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (data.txt) DO (

  SET "name=%%A"
  SET "name=!ext:name of file: =!"

  IF "!name!"=="%%A" (
    XYZ.exe %%A
  ) ELSE (
    IF DEFINED NotTheFirstName (
      do whatever you need with !oldname!
      to process your output files
    )
    SET "oldname=!name!"
    SET NotTheFirstName=1
  )
)
do whatever you need with !oldname! once again
(to account for the last set of output files)
```

Note that if `data.txt` was formatted like this:

```
abc 1 2
xyz 2 3
name of file: mp3
sss 1 2
rrr 2 3
name of file: mp4
eee 1 2
qqq 2 3
name of file: vob
```

i.e. if the file name line was *after* the param lines it pertained to, the script would be much simpler:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelatedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (data.txt) DO (

  SET "name=%%A"
  SET "name=!ext:name of file: =!"

  IF "!name!"=="%%A" (
    XYZ.exe %%A
  ) ELSE (
    do whatever you need with !name!
    to process your output files
  )
)
```

As you can see, there's no need to store the name for use at a later iteration, because the output is processed just there and then. And, consequently, there's no need for any flags or for using the name once again just after the loop.